# android multiple screen sizes

Tags: java, android, xml, android-activity

I have 3 activity_main.xml files in a folder a normal, large and xlarge file each, when I run the app on the Android Studio emulator on the Nexus 4, Nexus 7 and Nexus 10 they all have the regular main file showing not the large or xlarge. Am I missing something?.

As requested here's some screenshots of the files:

[Full res folder in Windows Explorer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zvmwr.png)

[res folder in Android Studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nh8KC.png)

Comment: Can you attach something, eg screenshots, layout files structure, main parts of activity_main.xml bla bla. We need to see what you have so far.

Comment: Suggested reading: https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct folders to limit between phone, 7" tablet and 10" tablet are:

```
layout/            (default)
layout-sw600dp/    (7")
layout-sw720dp/    (10")
```

`sw` is: "smallest available width"

you can read more about it here: https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

> Beginning with Android 3.2 (API level 13), the above size groups are deprecated and you should instead use the swdp configuration qualifier to define the smallest available width required by your layout resources

Comment: That didn't work however, I changed the emulator to the 7" WSGA Tablet and 10" WSGA Tablet and the original large/xlarge worked.